# Operations in a for loop only apply to the last file in imageJ

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I have a folder of images that I want to subtract a background file from them. I store the background file in another folder. I wrote the macro below but it only operates on the last file:

```
setBatchMode(true); 

input_to_files = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/FL_20191115_40540 PM/";
input_to_BG =  "C:/Users/user/Desktop/BG/";
output = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/SumZ/";

function action(input_file, filename, inputBG, bg, output) {
        open(input_file + filename);
        open(inputBG + bg);
        imageCalculator("Subtract create stack", filename, bg);
        saveAs("tif", output + filename);
        close();
}

list = getFileList(input_to_files);
background =  getFileList(input_to_BG);

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        filename = list[i];
        bg = background[0];
        action(input_to_files, filename, input_to_BG, bg, output)

setBatchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop should be in braces and the final line of the loop needs a terminating semi-colon:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        filename = list[i];
        print(filename);
        bg = background[0];
        action(input_to_files, filename, input_to_BG, bg, output);
}
```